# load multi-modal data with pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to load multi-modal data (e.g. text and image) in pytorch for image classification. I do not know how to load them simultaneously, like the following code.

```
 def __init__(self, img_path, txt_path, transform=None, loader=default_loader):

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.img_name)

def __getitem__(self, item):
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In `__getitem__`, you can use a dictionary or a tuple to represent one sample of your data. Later during training when you create a dataloader using the dataset, pytorch will automatically create batches of dictonary or tuples.

If you want to create samples in a much more different way, check out collate_fn in pytorch.

Answer (score 0):

The method getitem(self, item) would help you do this.

For example:

```
def __getitem__(self, item):  # item can be thought as an index
    
    text = textList[item]  # textList would be a list containing the text you want to input into the model for element 'item'
    img = imgList[item]  # imgList would be a list containing the images you want to input into the model for element 'item'
   
    input = [text, img]  
    y = labels[item]  # labels would be a list containing the label for the input of the text and img. This is your target.
    
    return input, y
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try it.